# Xcode rebuild entirely my project when I can a single file

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode3.2

Xcode rebuild entirely my project when I can a single file.
Node: the file I'm changing is not the .pch file. this is happening to me after the installation of Xcode 3.2.4 with SDK 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

XCode will rebuild whatever files are necessary to make sure all changes to files are correct.  This means that if you change CCNode.c in the cocos2d directory, your going to rebuild all of cocos2d and anything in your project that referenced it.

Without stating what file your changing, or how it relates to your project hierarchy, it's really hard to answer your question.